# Reference request for Galois Theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, galois-theory, book-recommendation

I am an undergraduate taking a second semester course in Abstract Algebra. We just got started on Field and Galois theory, and my professor told us that he will teach us Grothendieck's formulation of Galois theory. He started talking about (basic) category theory, étale algebra, separable extensions, category of finite G-sets.

Can someone point me in the direction of one or several self-contained expositions of this approach to Galois theory that is suitable for a relatively inexperienced undergraduate? I have taken all the basic courses (calculus, linear algebra etc) plus a semester in topology and algebra, and I would like to see clear exposition with lots of examples if possible. Thank you.

Comment: Done. Also [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1063120/29335). I found these by typing "Grothendieck galois theory" in the search bar.

Comment: @rschwieb I have seen the two questions you linked before submitting my question. In those cases, the askers have stronger background than me, studying algebraic geometry and homological algebra. As someone relatively new to abstract algebra I am hoping for something more elementary.

Comment: Can I recommend my blog? It has three good posts on it. https://edeany.com